# Django - How to show two localized dates in two different languages on the same webpage?

Tags: django, date, localization

I have one webpage with two paragraphs (original and translated) in two different languages (Arabic and Hebrew) at the same time.
Each paragraph is shown in a different column on the page.
As a header for each column i want to use localized date according to the columns language

Is there any way to switch language inside the template before using "|localize" filter ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is {% language %} tag
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#switching-language-in-templates